# IE6 only allowing $.get(..) through server

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-6, get, portability

I am not sure if this issue exists in other browsers; however, if I am simply trying to run a jquery $.get() in IE6, without running through a server, then it[$.get] will fail. As in it wont actually get the file. I am simply trying to grab an xml file in the same directory. I am trying to bundle this stuff up on a disk and distribute them. Is there a workaround for this?  I suppose a workaround could be an executable that acts as a server or something and gets executed via autorun.inf.

Input?
Thanks!!!

Comment: If there is no actual server communication, why use .get?  Why not just include the data in javascript variables?

Comment: true... The file is just an extremely large XML file though. I would have preferred it to be seperate, but I suppose that is unnecessary

Comment: What do you mean by "without running through a server"?

Comment: It must run through something like apache. It will not work in IE6 if you simply open a html file from a folder on your desktop.

Comment: Thats great and all, except you forget that in the corporate world thats all they use... i blame oracle personally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if i had known about this sooner: http://www.server2go-web.de/download/download.html
allows for a totally portable installation free, fully customizable server!